Can I take a screenshot of a program running from a pendrive?
Can I take a screenshot of a program running from a pen-drive?
Clonezilla is on a bootable pen drive.
I need help with Clonezilla, when it is running from a pendrive that I have booted from.
Those screenshots would be better than taking pictures with my camera.
I could post those pics in a question to make my questions more clear.
Please pay attention to what you are reading.
And ask probing questions.

What happens if you press the PrtScr button?

@Will Nothing occurs when I hit PrtScr.

On an Ubuntu Desktop system, the most popular, it's very easy to take a screenshot by pressing PrtScr. Since that does not work for you, maybe you have a broken keyboard. Or maybe you are running a different flavor of Ubuntu. Or perhaps a different OS entirely. Other possibilities past that. Please edit your question to preclude the need for clairvoyance and speculation.

@user535733 Nothing wrong with my keyboard. What are not understanding? I have to work as if I am walking on eggshells.

I think what the other comment is getting at is - we don’t even know what version of Ubuntu you’re using nor  anything about your hardware. Those details matter to help people solve your problem.

@Will thanks. I modified my post.

Unless the pen drive was created with persistence, you cannot save the screenshot.

@Organic Marble If I post pictures from my phone, will someone help me?

you might find Pastebin useful

Clonezilla is mainly a bootable distribution that is used for cloning partitions. Do you use it as such? Because in your question you mention Ubuntu Mate 24.04. If you have it somehow installed on Ubuntu Mate, we should also know how you installed it, if your Ubuntu Mate is a Live version, etc. So unless I don't understand something, your question is either unclear because it lacks important information, or is off-topic because it is about Clonezilla, which is not Ubuntu.

@BeastOfCaerbannog There is a lot of misunderstanding occurring. I will read all the comments and edit my question. I do my best I but can not anticipate every scenario.

@AndrewK Your edit clarified things a bit. So, since you are using Clonezilla on your USB device and this is what you have trouble with (not Ubuntu), your question is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu, because Clonezilla is not Ubuntu. You have some answers already, but if you need more help, you can try asking in Unix & Linux, which accepts questions about all Linux distributions. Your question here will most likely be closed soon as not being about Ubuntu. I hope you understand.

press Alt+Prnt-Sys-req keyz!!

I have asked others to look at my post. They understand the question.

Maybe you can screenshot the whole monitor screen by pressing the PrtScn key and then crop it down to size in GIMP image editor.
Many live environments, including Clonezilla's, support the fbcat command (sudo apt install fbcat) which captures the framebuffer (the screen's raw output). You can use this command.
sudo fbcat > screenshot.ppm

This will save a screenshot in ppm format, which you can convert to another format (like png) later using an image editor like GIMP. ppm is a raw image format, so don't be surprised at how large screenshot.ppm is.

Why would I upload it? Is it not stored on my hard drive?

You don't need to upload it if the bootable pen drive was created with persistent file storage, so you can save it there. What is important is that you manage to save the screenshot somehow.

Alright. I will have to see if I installed Clonezilla in persistent storage. You make me work to hard.

The persistent file storage feature can be enabled in a bootable Ubuntu live USB if you are running Clonezilla from an Ubuntu live session on a bootable USB. The Clonezilla app does not have a similar persistence feature and neither does the bootable Clonezilla live USB. There's no need to overthink it. Just make sure that the screenshot is saved somewhere.

You are funny. I do not think I am overthinking. Taking a picture with my phone is the most efficient.

Whatever just as long as you manage to save the screenshot.

fbcat produced a file from the "twilight zone."

It's time to either screenshot the whole monitor screen or else use your phone.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If I understand you correctly, you run a text mode application (without GUI) from a bootable USB drive.
In that case there is no possibility to take a screenshot via software, as there's no GUI to support the screenshot functionality. You have to use a camera.
Some computers have BIOS-level screenshot support, in that case you could be able to take a screenshot of a text mode application, but this may require connecting to so called "management engine" (may be called differently on different computer brands) of your computer from another computer using the web browser. You must check your computer's documentation for this.

I just took some pictures with my phone.
